# how to specify ulimit on nvidia-docker runing on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: docker, nvidia

Team: Need some help here..

Subject: insert `--default-ulimit memlock=16777216:16777216` in

```
/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker-options.conf
```

Issue: System is running `nvidia-docker` and after insertion of above, reload systemd and restart docker, the containers on this node are still not reflecting the value that am setting. I then tried on a different system which is running generic docker and there I am able to see the ulimit is immediately reflected.
Clarification: does `nvidia-docker` depends on some other file for ulimit to take effect ?

```
cat  /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker-options.conf
[Service]
Environment="DOCKER_OPTS=  --data-root=/var/lib/docker --log-opt max-size=50m --log-opt max-file=5 --iptables=false --default-ulimit memlock=16777216:16777216"
```

Not sure if below file is interfering but then why it works as expected on generic docker node?

```
cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker-override.conf 
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -s overlay2 --default-shm-size=1G
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
LimitSTACK=67108864
```

or do I need to specify in daemon file  since this system is running `nvidia-docker`? not sure so wanted to be sure before I make changes, also please let know how exactly the syntax should be as am new..

```
cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{
    "bip": "10.10.1.1/24",
    "default-runtime": "nvidia",
    "registry-mirrors": [
        "https://mirror.gcr.io"
    ],
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "/usr/bin/nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs": []
        }
    }
```

test from non nvidia docker system when  flag was set in docker options file.

```
kubectl exec -ti -n team-telegraf   team-telegraf-4b5l2 -- bash -c "ulimit -l"
16384. <<<<< Observe
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Example copied from [here](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/How-To-Setup-NVIDIA-Docker-and-NGC-Registry-on-your-Workstation---Part-5-Docker-Performance-and-Resource-Tuning-1119/).

```
{
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "/usr/bin/nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs": []
        }
    },

    "default-ulimits": {
         "memlock": { "name":"memlock", "soft":  -1, "hard": -1 },
         "stack"  : { "name":"stack", "soft": 67108864, "hard": 67108864 }
    }
}
```